# how to remove text after symbol or phrase in cell vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that would loop through a large set of rows (one particular column) and remove text if a specific word is found. Unfortunately I am not getting anywhere with that and was hoping that the community could help.

An example of the line would be

"One"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit "sixty_six" sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Desired outcome after macro would complete it's task would be:

"One"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit

so everything starting with "sixty_six" and after would be deleted.

The code that I have so far is:

```
Sub removeData()

Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow

    If InStr(i.Value, "sixty_six") > 0 Then
        i.Value = Left(i.Value, InStr(i.Value, "sixty_six") - 1)
    End If

Next i


End Sub
```

The error that I am getting states "Invalid Qualifier" but not sure how I can fix it.

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: `Split` on your target value (`"sixty_six"`) and then output the first element of the resulting array

Comment: `i` is a `Long` and as such doesn't have a `.Value`.

Comment: You can also use Find and Replace for this with a wildcard: Find `"sixty_six"*`.

Comment: I've tried to remove .Value, but that did not change anything: 

Sub removeData()

Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow

If InStr(i, "sixty_six") > 0 Then
        i = Left(i, InStr(i, "sixty_six") - 1)
    End If


Next i


End Sub

Comment: `i` is a `Long` (2, 3, 4)... :-). Use it within `Cells` or with `Range`.

Comment: Alright, it did work with Cells(i), but seems like only with one row instead of going through a loop

Comment: You don't need a loop (or VBA) here btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, declare a worksheet so you can properly qualify your objects here. You are also looping through a invalid range - see proper way to loop through all rows on a column below *(assuming your strings to be changed are in `Column C`)*

---

Assuming your value `"sixty_six"` will either appear **once** or **not at all**, you can use `Split` to convert your string into two elements where:

- The first element is everything before `"sixty_six"`
- The second element is everything after (and including) `"sixty_six"`

*If "sixty_six" does not appear in the string, the entire string will be held in the first element*

---

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim i As Long, lr As Long
Dim arr

lr = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lr
    arr = Split(ws.Range("C" & i), """sixty_six""")

    ws.Range("C" & i) = arr(0)

    arr = ""
Next i
```

---

### Alternative

You can avoid VBA all together by just using search and replace ( <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>F</kbd> ) with a wildcard search of `"sixty_six"*` and a replacement of  (a blank string).

Highlight target column and select `Replace All`.

[image]

@BigBen for calling out non-excel solution

Comment: It's worth noting that you can also recreate the find & search feature in VBA and remove your need to loop altogether

Comment: May I sugest: `ws.Range("C" & i) = Split(ws.Range("C" & i), """sixty_six""")(0)` =) kudos for the `Split`